# Pass "this" parameter to another class

Tags: c#, winforms

Assuming, my Form is NO BORDER, and i will make a image will be a Custom title bar

i want to creat class calling TitleBar, have a method ApplyTitleBar(Control c);
and in any Form in project, just calling the ApllyTitleBar() to any Control on Form, when mouse Down and mouse move, the Form moving too.

Code in class TitleBar:

```
public class TitleBar
{
    private bool drag = false; // determine if we should be moving the form
    private Point startPoint = new Point(0, 0);

    public void ApplyTitleBar(Control c)
    {
        c.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(panelTitleBar_MouseUp);
        c.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(panelTitleBar_MouseMove);
        c.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(panelTitleBar_MouseDown);

    }

    void panelTitleBar_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.drag = false;
    }
    void panelTitleBar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.startPoint = e.Location;
        this.drag = true;
    }
    void panelTitleBar_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.drag)
        { // if we should be dragging it, we need to figure out some movement
            Point p1 = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            Point p2 = this.PointToScreen(p1);
            Point p3 = new Point(p2.X - this.startPoint.X,
                                 p2.Y - this.startPoint.Y);
            this.Location = p3;
        }
    }


}
```

Assume in another Form, i have label lblTitleBar and want it will be a "titleBar"

```
TitleBar tb=new TitleBar();
tb.Apply(lblTitleBar);
```

I know "this" parameter in class TitleBar cannot have method Location() and PointToScreen() because that "this" is instance of TitleBar, not of Form.
Is there another way to passing a class to this, or way to do that???

```
tb.Apply(lblTitleBar,this);
```

Comment: I'm finding your first paragraph very hard to understand - I've edited as best I can, but the end part - "like of Form I mean MouseDown on it and a form will moving" - is too hard for me to understand. Could you try rewording it?

Comment: Your `TitleBar` class doesnt have an `Apply` method!?

Comment: thanks.
Assuming, myForm is NO BORDER, and i will make a image will be a title bar for moving Form.
i want to creat class calling TitleBar, have a method ApplyTitleBar(Control c);
and in any Form in project, just calling the ApllyTitleBar() to any Control on Form, when mouse Down and mouse move, the Form moving too.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after here is a reference back to the form:

```
public class TitleBar
{
    private bool drag = false; // determine if we should be moving the form
    private Point startPoint = new Point(0, 0);
    private Form form;

    public void ApplyTitleBar(Control c, Form f)
    {
        c.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(panelTitleBar_MouseUp);
        c.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(panelTitleBar_MouseMove);
        c.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(panelTitleBar_MouseDown);
        this.form = f;

    }
    ....
```

Then later on you can do this:

```
void panelTitleBar_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.drag)
    { // if we should be dragging it, we need to figure out some movement
        Point p1 = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        Point p2 = form.PointToScreen(p1);
        Point p3 = new Point(p2.X - form.startPoint.X,
                             p2.Y - form.startPoint.Y);
        form.Location = p3;
    }
}
```

And, assuming you instantiate all this from *within* the form you would indeed call it like so:

```
tb.ApplyTitleBar(lblTitleBar,this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to retrieve the Form the target control is contained on.

```
void panelTitleBar_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Control control = sender as Control;
    if(null != control)
    {
        Form form = control.FindForm();
        if(null != form)
        {
            if (this.drag)
            { // if we should be dragging it, we need to figure out some movement
                Point p1 = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                Point p2 = form.PointToScreen(p1);
                Point p3 = new Point(p2.X - this.startPoint.X,
                                     p2.Y - this.startPoint.Y);
                form.Location = p3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```